# select a row for each column`s value

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have got a condition and i want to use mysql temporary tables.

i have **Tasks** table and **Jobs** table.

tasks has one to many relation with jobs (each task has one or more jobs)

i want to select The **Last Job** of each task in a query (based on created_at column).

this query works fine:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tasks t
  join jobs j
    on t.id = j.task_id 
   and j.id = ( select id 
                  from jobs 
                 where jobs.task_id = t.id 
                   and jobs.deleted_at is null 
                 order 
                    by id desc 
                 limit 1
              ) 
 order 
    by j.created_at desc;
```

but i want to use something more flexible like mysql temporary table:

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE last_jobs SELECT * from jobs where ...`

and make it with laravel elequent and  query builder if there is any built in function or so like:

`Task::select('tasks.*,jobs.*')->join('jobs')->where()`

if anyone can give me a hand or a clue it would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: What's so great about temporary tables?

Comment: it gets difficult to make sub query in laravel  query builder. and nested blocks. but with temporary tables i can avoid nesting and write cleaner code. and made it easier to work with query builder libraries.

Comment: So perhaps your question is really about avoiding subqueries. Well, I think that's a mistake, because a subquery is likely to be more efficient in this instance (although maybe not this precise subquery)

Comment: Sure. Avoiding sub query :)

Comment: finally i made it like this and it works fine:

```DB::statement("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE last_jobs SELECT jobs.* from jobs join tasks on tasks.id=jobs.task_id and jobs.id=(select id from jobs where jobs.task_id=tasks.id and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null order by `id` desc limit 1);");```
        
and furture:

```$query = Task::select("tasks.*")->join("last_jobs","tasks.id","last_jobs.task_id");```
in my php code.

Comment: as you see it gets very easy to use with temp table.

Comment: Hm, If you say so.

Comment: Why a temporary table and not a view?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Rwd version 5.8

Comment: @apokryfos maybe using view is better. i dont know about mysql views a lot but after your comment i took a look and they seems great. can you make an example my desired query using **view**? how to conditional select rows in them ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view in a migration, note that you should explicitly declare each column name (with an alias if it is an ambiguous name).

```php
class CreateLastJobsView extends Migration {
   public function up() {
    DB::statement("CREATE VIEW last_jobs AS
       SELECT t.id as task_id, j.id as job_id, ...  
       FROM tasks t
       join jobs j
         on t.id = j.task_id 
       and j.id = ( select id 
                  from jobs 
                 where jobs.task_id = t.id 
                   and jobs.deleted_at is null 
                 order 
                    by id desc 
                 limit 1
              ) 
        order by j.created_at desc");
  }

  public function down()  {
    DB::statement('DROP VIEW last_jobs');
  }  

}
```

Then you can use the view as a normal table:

```php
DB::table('last_jobs')->select('task_id')->first();
```